# Use repeat in nested loop without parent elements?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to print out the error messages using the code below. As you can see, since the message is inside an associative array (object) 3 levels deep I have to use 3 loops. The outer divs are actually pretty useless and I want to get rid of the if possible. However, since ng-repeat requires putting it to a real div, I don't know what else I can do?

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(typeKey, typeValue) in alerts">
    <div data-ng-repeat="(fieldKey, fieldValue) in typeValue">
        <div data-ng-repeat="(messageKey, messageValue) in fieldValue">
            {[ messageValue ]}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not just flatten the json first?

Answer (score 0):

As I know angulajs does not support containerless syntax. If you want to get rid of divs than you can write a function on controller to generate your message values without divs:

```
<div>
    getMessages(alerts)
</div>
```